# Tensorflow Diff Between Two Collections

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting collections of variables that I want to run with a separate optimizer using `tf.get_collection()`'s scope regex.  I then want to have a separate collection that contains all of the other variables not contained in the collection that I specify so that I can make sure all of these variables are passed to the other optimizer. I have come up with one approach, but I'm not sure if it is the most efficient. Is there a better way to do this within tensorflow? Consider the example below..

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

graph=tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

```
with tf.name_scope('some_scope1'):
    a = tf.Variable(1, 'a')
    b = tf.Variable(2, 'b')
    c = tf.Variable(3, 'c')

with tf.name_scope('some_scope2'):
    d = tf.Variable(4, 'd')
    e = tf.Variable(5, 'e')
    f = tf.Variable(6, 'f')

h = tf.Variable(8, 'h')

trainable_collection = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
scope_collection = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='some_scope')
no_scope = [var for var in trainable_collection if var not in scope_collection]

for i in trainable_collection:
    if i not in scope_collection:
        print i.name   # i.name if you want just a name

for i in no_scope:
    print i.name
```

`no_scope` does contain all of the variables that weren't included in `scope_collection` but I wasn't sure if this was the best way to do this? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I think this the fasted way to get the complement of a variable_scope. What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I just wasn’t sure if I was missing some option that existed.